# check existence of reactive in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where you can upload some raw data and build a summarizedExperiment (let's call it RAW) or you can upload an already processed summarizedExperiment (let's call it FINAL). Now I need to save in a reactive object RAW or FINAL. I tried something like this:

```
  sumexp_all = reactive({

    if(!is.null(RAW())){
      list(sumexp_data = RAW()$sumexp_data, sumexp_data_mean = RAW()$sumexp_data_mean, replicates = RAW()$replicates)
    }else if(!is.null(input$finalsumexpinput)){
      readRDS(file = input$finalsumexpinput$datapath)
    }else{
      NULL
    }
  })
```

But in this case it works only if I have RAW (if I don't have RAW (so should be NULL since there are many `req()` in the pipeline) and I want to upload FINAL, nothing happens). If reverse the if conditions (before FINAL and then RAW) I can upload the FINAL. What's wrong? Is it correct to evaluate a reactive with `is.null()`?

I tried something else like this:

```
  sumexp_all = reactive({
    checkerror <- tryCatch(RAW(), error = function(e) "empty")
    if(checkerror != "empty"){
      list(sumexp_data = RAW()$sumexp_data, sumexp_data_mean = RAW()$sumexp_data_mean, replicates = RAW()$replicates)
    }else if(!is.null(input$finalsumexpinput)){
      readRDS(file = input$finalsumexpinput$datapath)
    }else{
      NULL
    }
  })
```

But the shiny app crashes and returns this error:

```
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
```

And that's weird because if I print `checkerror` it correctly returns "empty" if's empty.

---

UPDATE:

I made some testing in order to find where is the problem, and the problem is with the `RAW()` reactive. Basically I tried this code to find the problem:

```
  checkraw = reactive({
    if(is.null(RAW())){
      "raw is null"
    }else{
      "raw is not null"
    }
    })
  
  checkinp = reactive({
    if(is.null(input$finalsumexpinput$datapath)){
      "input non loaded"
    }else{
      "input loaded"
    }
  })
  
  output$printcheck= renderPrint({
   paste(checkraw(), ",", checkinp())
  })
```

So what I expect from this code is that if `RAW()` doesn't exist and I uplaod the rds file, it' printed `"raw is null, input loaded"`, but what happens is that **nothing** is displayed.
If `RAW()` exists then it's correctly printed `"raw is not null, input not loaded"`

Then I tried to print only `checkinp()` (removing the `checkraw()` reactive) and then `checkinp()` is correctly printed.

So it seems to me that the problem is in the evaluation of the `RAW()` reactive. Do you think that the problem could be that `RAW()` depends on others reactive variables (so there is a `req()` inside it).

EDIT:

Here is a reproducible example.

```
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("check"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("Button", "enable raw"),
    textInput("text", "write something", "something..."),
    br(),
      ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("printcheck"),
    verbatimTextOutput("checkfin")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  stepa = eventReactive(input$Button, {
    rnorm(100)
  })

stepb = reactive({
  req(stepa())
  stepa() * 100
})
output$printcheck = renderPrint({
  is.null(stepb())
})

fin = reactive({
  if(!is.null(stepb())){
    stepb()
  }else{input$text}
})

output$checkfin = renderPrint({
  fin()
})

  
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

As you can see `output$checkfin` is printed ONLY if `stepb()` is not null even if in this case should be printed `input$text`

Comment: Do you *know* which of those `if` statements is causing the error? Add `browser()` before the first `if` statement and start investigating *manually/interactively* at all of the variables and what you think their state is.

Comment: r2evans is right. You have to give us more information. Basically it is correct to evaluate a reactive with `is.null()`. In a shiny context I'd prefer `isTruthy` rather than `!is.null()` but that shouldn'T make a difference here. I tried it in an own sample and it worked fine.

Comment: Furthermore, it is strange that `tryCatch` yields an exception. If RAW is just some normal reactive expression it should be defined. It may give you `NULL` but that is valid. I did not get an error but just `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry for late. I edited the original post with some testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the problem on the shiny github page. For those interested, here's the answer.

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3533